# Why am I getting a Connection Timeout while just trying to connect to ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

Using the Java version of the FuelSDK, I'm unable to get a connection to our instance of ExactTarget. I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSdkException: error writing https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.sendRequest(ETRestConnection.java:222)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.sendRequest(ETRestConnection.java:166)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.post(ETRestConnection.java:107)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.post(ETRestConnection.java:136)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.refreshToken(ETClient.java:176)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.sendRequest(ETRestConnection.java:199)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.sendRequest(ETRestConnection.java:166)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.sendRequest(ETRestConnection.java:154)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.get(ETRestConnection.java:92)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.<init>(ETClient.java:126)
at com.mt.ecom.transformer.EleadToExactTargetTransformer.sendLeadData(EleadToExactTargetTransformer.java:449)
at com.mt.ecom.transformer.EleadToExactTargetTransformer.transform(EleadToExactTargetTransformer.java:514)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:97)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:81)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:103)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:227)
at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:56)
at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:67)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:82)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection.sendRequest(ETRestConnection.java:218)
... 53 more
```

I suspect it might have something to do with my fuelsdk.properties file. I'm setting my clientId and clientSecret based on what I'm getting from the App Center, but have no idea what I should be setting endpoint, authEndpoing, or soapEndpoint.

Could there be some other configuration that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall by any chance? Have you tried connecting on a direct connection - does it work in that case?

Comment: OK, so when I connect from outside my company network, I'm able to get the connection. So this brings us to the next question. Am I able to configure a proxy in FuelSdk or do I need a firewall hole? If a firewall hole, what port?

Comment: Did you happen to solve your problem? If you did you can post your solution here so others (like me) may benefit from what you found. Thanks

Comment: I did, by re-writing the entire app to use a newer version of fuelsdk.